# How do I use generics to call a method with a Class parameter?

Tags: java, generics

I have a class that uses reflection to manipulate other classes:

```
package com.cw.cmt;

public class Container<T extends Class<?>> {
    private final Class<T> clazz;

    public Container(final Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        System.out.println("Expensive constructor for " + this);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Container [clazz=%s]", clazz);
    }
}
```

Because these are potentially expensive to construct, I want to cache them in a Map so that they are only constructed as needed:

```
package com.cw.cmt;

import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;

public class ContainerCache {
    private static final ConcurrentMap<Class<?>, Container<? extends Class<?>>> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public static <C extends Class<?>> Container<C> getContainer(final Class<C> clazz) {
        final Container<? extends Class<?>> result = cache.computeIfAbsent(clazz, k -> new Container<C>(clazz));
        // it would be nice to eliminate this cast!
        return (Container<C>) result;
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble working out the correct generic syntax for invoking this getContainer method.

```
// The parameterized method <Class<String>>getContainer(Class<Class<String>>) of type ContainerCache 
// is not applicable for the arguments (Class<String>)
ContainerCache.getContainer(String.class);

// Bound mismatch: The generic method getContainer(Class<C>) of type ContainerCache is not applicable 
// for the arguments (Class<String>). The inferred type String is not a valid substitute for the bounded 
// parameter <C extends Class<?>>
ContainerCache.<String>getContainer(String.class);

// The parameterized method <Class<String>>getContainer(Class<Class<String>>) of type ContainerCache 
// is not applicable for the arguments (Class<String>)
ContainerCache.<Class<String>>getContainer(String.class);
```

Comment: why would you want a container to store the `Class` of a `Class`?

Comment: `private final Class<T> clazz;` should be `private final T clazz;` I think

Comment: @Paul This is a simplification. The real Container is a class that does reflective stuff with objects of the target class, for which there are many use cases.

Comment: @Chris maybe, but that doesn't answer the question. all you'd need is the class of the type you want to manipulate, not the class of the class of the type you want to manipulate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can eliminate the cast because your map contains several "types" of containers so you need to cast to the correct one.
As pointed out your Container should be a `Container<T>` and a few more casts in your `getContainer` should do what you wanted:

```
public static class ContainerCache {
  private static final Map<Class<?>, Container<?>> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  public static <T> Container<T> getContainer(final Class<T> clazz) {
    return (Container<T>) cache.computeIfAbsent(clazz, c -> new Container<> ((Class<T>) c));
  }
}

public static class Container<T> {
  private final Class<T> clazz;

  public Container(final Class<T> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
    System.out.println("Expensive constructor for " + this);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.format("Container [clazz=%s]", clazz);
  }
}
```

It's a bit ugly but I don't think you can do much better...

Comment: Is there a difference between `c -> new Container<> ((Class<T>) c )` and `c -> new Container<T>(clazz)` ?

Comment: @Nizil they are functionally equivalent in this case, but the former is a non capturing lambda which can be more efficient I believe...

Comment: @assylias That's the right answer. It looks like I overcomplicated the issue with unnecessary attempts to constrain the type. The distinction between the types of lambda is interesting, though it's a pity the non-capturing lambda requires a cast.

Comment: @Joop Eggen The return type is a container for the class, not an instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a little mistake in your `Container`

```
public class Container<T extends Class<?>> {
  private final Class<T> clazz;
}
```

So, `clazz` is a `Class<Class<?>>` because `T extends Class<?>`.

A simple correction:

```
public class Container<T> {
  private final Class<T> clazz;
}
```

and

```
public class ContainerCache {
    private static final ConcurrentMap<Class<?>, Container<?>> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public static <T> Container<T> getContainer(final Class<T> clazz) {
        return (Container<T>) (cache.computeIfAbsent(clazz, k -> new Container<T>(clazz)));
    }
}
```

Actually, I don't have a nice solution to avoid the cast :)